# Cinema seating plan for python

Tags: python

I am creating a seating plan for a movie theater and I am having a problem with adding a seat request after already purchasing one seat.

Here is the code I have been working on

```
print("Options for Black Panther the movie")
def display_seats(taken_seats):
    seating = []
    for xd in range(15):
        row = []
        xda = 0
        for xda in range(15):
            row.append("#")
        seating.append(row)
    for x in taken_seats:
        pos = x.split(",")
        seating[(int(pos[0]) - 1)][(int(pos[1]))] = "X"
    dx = 1
    for row in seating:
        if len(str(dx)) < 2:
            de = " " + str(dx)
        else:
            de = dx
        print ("Row: " + str(de) + " ".join(row))
        dx = dx + 1
def list_options():
    print ("1: View current seating")
    print ("2: view price per row")
    print ("3: View how much you are paying for now")
    print ("4: Buying tickets")
    print ("5: Exit these options")
    new_input = input("Your choice: ")
    return (new_input)
def purchase_seat(taken_seats):
    print ("Would you like to view current seating availability? ")
    print ("'1' = yes, '2' = no")
    newinput = input("? ")
    if newinput == "1":
        display_seats(taken_seats)
    x = True
    while x == True:
        cost = 0
        print ("what row would you like to buy a seat on? ")
        rowx = input("What row? ")
        print ("What seat would you like to purchase?")
        rowy = input("what seat? ")
        if any((str(rowx) + "," + str(rowy)) for x in taken_seats):
            print ("That seat is already taken, please choose another seat.")
        elif int(rowx) > 15 or int(rowy) > 15:
            print ("Invalid seating location, please choose another seat.")
        else:
            print ("seat purchased.")
            cost = (2 * int(rowx))
            x = False
    return (cost, (str(rowx) + "," + str(rowy)))
taken_seats = []
sales = 0
quitter = 0
while quitter == 0:
    new_input = list_options()
    if new_input == "5":
        quitter = 1
    elif new_input == "4":
        g = True
        while g == True:
            new_seat = purchase_seat(taken_seats)
            taken_seats.append(new_seat[1])
            print ("That will be: $ " + str(new_seat[0]))
            sales = sales + new_seat[0]
            print ("Would you like to purchase another seat?")
            new_input = input("'1' = yes, '2' = no: ")
            if new_input == "1":
                pass
            else:
                g = False
    elif new_input == "3":
        print ("Total sales: $" + str(sales))
    elif new_input == "2":
        xd = 0
        while xd < 15:
            print ("Row for the theater " + str(xd + 1) + ": is $" + str((1 + (2 * xd)) + 1))
            xd = xd + 1
    elif new_input == "1":
        display_seats(taken_seats)
    else:
        print ("invalid option.")
```

After choosing option 4 and purchasing a seat and keep answering to input the row you want and the seat when you input another different row and seat coordinates it says "This seat has already been taken"

I have been looking everywhere for an answer and I cant seem to find something. Please help if you can, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `any` method returns:
`True` if at least one element of an iterable is true.
`False` if all elements are false or if an iterable is empty.
[Refer Python Documentation for any method usage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

Line 42 `if any((str(rowx) + "," + str(rowy)) for x in taken_seats):`, should actually be `if (str(rowx) + "," + str(rowy) in taken_seats):` .
That should check whether the selected seat is present in the list `taken_sets`.

Comment: No problem. If you are satisfied with the answer provided click on the tick provided on the left hand side.